# Bug in the code

Tags: c, printf, logical-operators

This code is always printing

> fine Rs. 1

Despite number of days entered is `> 30`. What is the reason?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int days;
    printf("enter no. of days");
    scanf("%d",&days);
    if (days<=5){printf("fine 50 paise");}
    else if (5<days<=10){printf("fine Rs. 1");}
    else if (10<days<30){printf("fine Rs.5");}
    else printf(" memebership cancelled");
}
```

Comment: Proper formatting of your code, particularly indentation, would make it *much* easier to read.

Comment: Adding a meaningful title would help, too.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate (I've answered questions about `x < y < z` before).

Answer (score 4):

change

```
if (5<days<=10)
```

to

```
if (5<days && days <= 10)
```

same for other(s).

Otherwise, in your code, the condition check behaves like

```
if ( (5 < days) <=10)
```

so, whatever value you enter for `days` [`6` and above, keeping the first `if` in mind], the result of the `<` operation will always produce either `0` or `1`, both being `<= 10`, thus making the condition TRUE, printing `fine Rs. 1`.

Related Reading: [C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Note: It's a good practice to add a `return` statement before the closing `}` of `main()`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `&&`?

Comment: The && operator is what you need here, not ||.

Answer (score 2):

C parses statements (such as `if(5<days<=10)`) in pieces, rather than trying to interpret them holistically.  What this means is that the compiler reads `if(5<days<=10)` as `if((5<days)<=10)`.  Note that this means that the **result** of `5<days` is compared to `10`, not the variable `days`.  To expand, the result of any comparison operator (`<`, `>`, `==`, etc) is an integer representing whether it is true or false (this is called a `boolean` value, a value which is either true or false), 1 or 0 respectively.  So, assuming `5<days` is true, the next comparison is `1<=10` (or `0<=10` if days is smaller than 5), which of course is always true.

To fix this, use the comparison operator `&&` (and).  `if(5 < days && days <= 10)` is parsed as `((5 < days) && (days <= 10))`, so you are correctly first comparing the `days` variable to `5` and `10`, then taking the truth value of each of those statements and seeing if `5 < days` **and** `days <= 10` is true.

One last point - `0` is always false, any non-zero is always true, so `if(0)` will always be false and `if(5)` will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the second if condition, i don't know if it is allowed to use condition the way you used in you code as:

```
if (5<days<=10)
```

edit it to

```
if(days > 5 && days <= 10)
```

and it will work, also edit the third condition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (5<days<=10)
```

is not of the right syntax

it should be

```
if(5<days && days<=10)
```

change it and your problem should be solved.   :)